# How can I group together multiple variables so they act the same?

Tags: javascript

I have an effect that I want to have happen to all 3 different elements when you hover any one of them but I'm having trouble grouping the variables together so they can all act the same

The code I wrote was what I thought would group them together.

```
 var germany=new Array(); 
    germany[0]=germany1_poly;      
    germany[1]=germany2_poly;
    germany[2]=germany3_poly;


google.maps.event.addListener(germany, "mouseover",function() {
     germany.setOptions({ fillColor: "#ff0000", strokeColor: "#ff0000" });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var i;
for(i = 0; i < germany.length; i++){
    google.maps.event.addListener(germany[i], "mouseover",function() {
         germany.setOptions({ fillColor: "#ff0000", strokeColor: "#ff0000" });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if i read your question correctly you want to update all three areas when a mouseover is observed on any one of them.
Here is some coffeescript that should help, and below it is the corrisponding javascript.

coffeescript:

```
germany = [
  germany1_poly      
  germany2_poly
  germany3_poly
]

areas_effect = (areas) ->
  for area in areas
    area.setOptions({ fillColor: "#ff0000", strokeColor: "#ff0000" })

areas_observer = (areas) ->
  for area in areas
    google.maps.event.addListener(area, "mouseover", areas_effect(areas))

areas_observer(germany)
```

javascipt:

```
var areas_effect, areas_observer, germany;
germany = [germany1_poly, germany2_poly, germany3_poly];
areas_effect = function(areas) {
  var area, _i, _len, _results;
  _results = [];
  for (_i = 0, _len = areas.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    area = areas[_i];
    _results.push(area.setOptions({
      fillColor: "#ff0000",
      strokeColor: "#ff0000"
    }));
  }
  return _results;
};
areas_observer = function(areas) {
  var area, _i, _len, _results;
  _results = [];
  for (_i = 0, _len = areas.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    area = areas[_i];
    _results.push(google.maps.event.addListener(area, "mouseover", areas_effect(areas)));
  }
  return _results;
};
areas_observer(germany);
```